# Want to define ViewBag just once in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In ASP.NET MVC controller, I have two Create and two Edit Actions. Each of these uses same `ViewBag`s. The problem is, if I want to change one `ViewBag`, I have to change it into four actions. Is there any way I can define all `Viewbag`s just one?

Comment: You could define the viewBag in the controllers constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a custom action filter:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.FooBar = "baz";
    }
}
```

and then decorate all your 4 actions with the `[MyActionFilter]` attribute.

Comment: Can I create a method and define all my viewbags inside that function and call that function from my create and edit actions?

Comment: Thanks Darin, I think this would be easier